# I'm trying to write a custom menu for Google Sheets but It's not showing up

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, permissions, menu

My code is below. I have tried refresh and re opening the sheet to no avail. I own and have full editing permissions on the sheet so I'm not sure why this doesn't work. Any help appreciated

```
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Custom Menu')
      .addItem('First item', 'menuItem1')
      .addSeparator()
      .addSubMenu(ui.createMenu('Sub-menu')
          .addItem('Second item', 'menuItem2'))
      .addToUi();
}

function menuItem1() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() 
       .alert('You clicked the first menu item!');
}

function menuItem2() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() 
     .alert('You clicked the second menu item!');
}
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Try opening your spreadsheet in incognito mode and only sign-in using the account that owns the spreadsheet. If the problem persist, add the execution logs and more details about your project i.e. how many files it have, the steps that you followed to create the project,...

Comment: @Rubén I Tried incognito, no joy. The execution log reads:                                                
      Error
Exception: Cannot call SpreadsheetApp.getUi() from this context.
onOpen @ Untitled.gs:2

Comment: @Rubén also spreadsheet has 11 sheets and is not huge. Can I share it with you?

Comment: ChrisParsons: First try to create a [mcve] 1. Create a new spreadsheet, 2. Click on Extensions > Apps Script. 3. Assign a name to the project (this a good habit to prevent having problems later) 4. Replace the default code by your code and save it, 5. In the toolbar, check that onOpen is shown, 6. In the toolbar click Run  7. Look at your spreadshsheet it should show the custom menu. 8. Refresh the spreadsheet to check that the onOpen trigger is working correctly.

Comment: @Rubén Don't know what I did, but I came to the conclusion that if the script was OK then it had to be do with the connection between the script and the spreadsheet. Think I may have saved it as a new project or something. Anyway, I copied it back in to the script editor from the spreadsheet route and it worked! Problem solved. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Hey I have just copy/paste your code. I also saved it and executed it. The custom menu appeared immediately.

After saving it did you execute it by any change? You need to click here

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to confirm that the file saved correctly and the necessary permissions have been granted to the script *(not just the user edit access permission)*.

This script you have here works just fine.